# API explorer/playground/sandbox for a custom API written in Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, custom-application

We'd like a simple API explorer written in Javascript to test our custom REST API that we are building for an iOS app.  The API sends GET and POST requests (POST requests  are sent with multipart/formdata encoding) and returns JSON.

I've found:

- apigee.com explorer (this is a hosted solution and quite complex to configure)
- mashery iodocs which is written in Node.JS
- Django API playground - which requires server-side stuff

As far as I can see this should be a purely client-side application - just form the requests, receive responses and display.  Surely someone must have written something like this already?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [Swagger UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/). Demo: http://petstore.swagger.io

Comment: Perfect - exactly what I wanted. Thanks!